Distribute balls with color and sum requirements

There are $3$ red balls, $3$ blue balls, $3$ green balls, and $3$ yellow balls. On each ball is written an integer in $[0,10]$. We want to distribute the balls into $4$ boxes, such that every box gets $3$ balls, all with different colors, and the sums of the numbers in any two boxes differ by at most $10$. Is this always possible?

If there was no requirement that every box gets $3$ balls, we could use a greedy strategy: proceed color by color, and for each color, successively throw the ball with the largest number into the box with the smallest sum, without repeating a box for this color. The invariant that the sums of the numbers in any two boxes differ by at most $10$ will be maintained. However, this strategy may give some boxes more than $3$ balls and some fewer than $3$.

Maybe it's just me missing something, but what does the coloring have to do with the task? As I understand it, the are 4 sets all having three integers, each in [0, 10], and the question is about maintaining the difference, while each integer can be any value in the given range, but shouldn't the coloring restrict the values?

@DávidLaczkó The coloring imposes constraints on how the balls can be distributed into boxes. The values are already given at the beginning, so the coloring doesn't restrict the values.

It is always possible.
From all allowed distributions of the balls over the boxes, consider the distributions where the greatest difference of the sums of distinct boxes is minimised. Among these distributions, pick one for which the number of "extremal boxes" (i.e. boxes whose sum is the largest or the smallest among all boxes in this distribution) is minimised. Take a box $i$ having the maximal sum $s_i$ and box $j$ having the minimal sum $s_j$. Suppose by way of contradiction that $s_i - s_j > 10$. Since $s_i > s_j$, there is some colour (say without loss of generality red) such that the red ball in box $i$ has greater value than the red ball in box $j$. Then box $j$ sums to a new value which is strictly smaller than $s_j$, but still greater than $s_i$. Likewise, box $i$ now sums to a value greater than $s_i$ but smaller than $s_j$. Therefore either the greatest difference between sums of boxes has decreased, or the number of extremal boxes has decreased. Either of those options contradict our initial assumptions.
